# SAAS AND Application Development Using REST

Tags: rest, saas

What is the difference between Software As a Service Applications and Development of application using REST.
Is it like SAAS applications are made using REST ?
What are the examples of SAAS. Can we say a Shopping Cart or a Quiz application a SAAS application if we make it using REST.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[REST](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Representational_state_transfer) is just an architectural style for designing network applications . As [Saas](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Software_as_a_service)  applications have to send data over the network, REST can be one of the ways to design them. Other can be service-oriented architecture ([SOA](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Service-oriented_architecture)).

Regarding your Shopping Cart or a Quiz application they will be SaaS applications as far as they are centrally hosted (can be accessed via internet in different parts of the globe). Its doesn't matter if it is REST based.

Comment: API Json if hosted can be accessed from different parts of the globe...to make application in android or Jquery to make web application. So can we say it a SAAS application?

Comment: It is definitely a SaaS application. Moreover you can have it in JSON or XML whatever format you require. Also that's the beauty of REST API' that you can call it from a web app, android app, ios app etc.